# how to open Gmail View Message Activity?

Tags: android, gmail

I want to write an application to List the Gmail message. In the list, if user click one of the message item, it shall link ot Gmail App to see more detial information. Currently I can read the Gmail db with Gmail.java.

There are some problems while I want to open Gmail Activity. In general, we can open Activity with Action and parameters. But Gmail App has not release code base. We do not know what Action set to Gmail Activity and what parmeter shall we put the extras. I only know that the Activity of View detial Message is named "HtmlConversationActivity." And the Package is under "com.google.android.gm."

Please tell me how to open the View detial Message Activity in Gmail APP.
    thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this link useful: [Start remote activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968631/start-sms-activity-conversarionlist-class-from-my-own-app)
My guess is that you'll need to pass some data to the other activity...

And if it doesn't sound too much like begging you could look at [this (How to get number of unread gmail mails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992635/how-to-get-the-number-of-unread-gmail-mails-on-android) to see if we can help each other :)